# how to set dynamic text content to yAxis stackLabels in HighCharts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, highcharts

I want to set `yAxis` `stackLabels` content dynamically display as in below link. **Good, Excellent, Poor, Average, Below Average**

Below link code is in `JavaScript`, how can I use it in `Objective C`?

Link : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yybLxgkd/98/)

`yAxis.stackLabel` doesn't have property with `qTotals` as used in link demo.

I want something like below image or display in above given link.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did u checked this .. https://www.highcharts.com/ios/demo/bar-stacked

Comment: @ShivamTripathi, Thanks for your reply but i don't need demo, I want any suggestion. as you see in given link I want stackedBar top Labels dynamically.

Comment: u can use data label property of columns like this :
    column.dataLabels.format = @"{point.y}";

Comment: @ShivamTripathi, `point.y` returns numeric value than displays on bars. if I write above line with some Predefine text than it will display in all Bars.

Comment: So, what info are you plotting current on y-axis? If u are plotting poor,good,excellent , etc : in that case point.y will return the same text.

Comment: `y-axis` `columns` values are numeric. display in Demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Solution.

If we want to set Text based on `yAxis` dataLabels total.

```
[HIStackLabels alloc]init];
yaxis.stackLabels.enabled = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:true];
yaxis.stackLabels.formatter = [[HIFunction alloc] initWithFunction:@"function() { if(this.total > 9) return 'Good'; if(this.y == 30) return 'Average';}"];
```

If we want to set Text Based on Particular Column.

```
column1.dataLabels = [[HIDataLabels alloc]init];
column1.dataLabels.enabled = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1];
column1.dataLabels.formatter = [[HIFunction alloc] initWithFunction:@"function() { if(this.y == 60) return 'Poor'; if(this.y == 30) return 'Average';}"];
```